# How to get Public and private keys?

Tags: openssl, key, private, public, pem

I have generated two files ***cert.pem*** and ***key.pem*** using OpenSSL command **req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365**
Now I want to get *public key from cert.pem file and private key from key.pem file*.
I have tried various methods but those method doesn't work for me.
I am gonna use these keys for encryption/decryption (Asymmetric).
I will use *public key for encryption* and *private key for decryption*.
Can somebody provide me methods/code to get those keys from those files.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a public key from private key by this commend.
you need phrase if you entered it during creating private key.

```
$ openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout > public_key.pem
```

You can see the content of public key

```
$ cat public_key.pem
```

Now you ready to encryption.
I will use plain text with simple message

```
$ echo 'secret message' > plain.txt
```

It makes to encrypt text

```
$ openssl enc -aes256 -base64 -e -in plain.txt -out cipher.txt
```

you needs to enter  password during it.
It's **-e** is to encrypt the **-in** file is input file.

```
$ cat cipher.txt
U2FsdGVkX18JKAGN3ECDpB0v1wtNdIuOxf8RYz8uMP4=
```

Finally you can make a decryption by this commend

```
$ openssl enc -aes256 -base64 -d -in cipher.txt -out plain_back.txt
```

```
$ cat plain_back.txt
secret message
```

Also you can make a signature file with certification file.
I will make zip file first with plain.txt

```
$ zip data.zip plain.txt
```

To sign a data file , OpenSSL digest (dgst) command is used.
you needs to enter pass phrase for key.pem

```
$ openssl dgst -sign key.pem -keyform PEM -sha256 -out data.zip.sign -binary data.zip
```

The digital signature can also be verified using the same openssl dgst command.

```
$ openssl dgst -verify public_key.pem -keyform PEM -sha256 -signature data.zip.sign -binary data.zip
Verified OK
```

Comment: Did I miss something ? The poster wanted to use the public/private keys for encryption and decryption but you are using AES with a passphrase and not the asymmetric keys.

Comment: This is encrypt by public key example. https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Encrypt_and_decrypt_files_to_public_keys_via_the_OpenSSL_Command_Line.html